# How to disable css rules on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I created a class in a wordpress css file

```
.leftfloat{ float:left; padding-right:10px; }
```

I use it in the posts to wrap text around images like so:

```
<div class ="leftfloat" > image code or ad code </leftfloat>
```

It's working on PC and mobile devices.  However, I want to **disable this float in mobile devices**. So I did this:

There is already `@media` defined in the template, I just added `.leftfloat {float: none;}`

But when I check it, it's not disabling float on mobile devices.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
        .leftfloat {float: none;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
        .leftfloat {float: none;} }

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .leftfloat {float: none;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
        .leftfloat {float: none;} }

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
         .leftfloat {float: none;}
```

Comment: Did you check to see if your browser has caching disabled.

Comment: try changing the `float:none` to `clear:both`.  I think the float is being set by the main styling and not being overridden by the media queries

Comment: What about that space after `class`? `class ="leftfloat"` should be  `class="leftfloat"`

Comment: Clear and float are different things. Clear applies to objects **next to** the floated object to make them not align. Thats completly different than trying to cancel a floating object

Comment: Another question... does your code work on the desktop when you shrink your browser down? If so that says its a browser compatibility issue (which autoprefixer can probably fix) and not a problem with your code.

Comment: Try with `@media (max-width:1020px){....}`, removing `screen and`

Comment: I checked many times on my mobile after clearing the browser and putting cloudflare on development mode.It didn't work.. But now after an hour i checked again now its working. Also i was testing it on http://mobiletest.me which was showing me cached version.

Answer (score 3):

Your complete CSS looks like:

```
.leftfloat{
  float:left;
  padding-right:10px;
}
   @media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
   .leftfloat {
     float: none;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
   .leftfloat {
     float: none;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .leftfloat {
     float: none;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
   .leftfloat {
     float: none;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
   .leftfloat {
     float: none;
   }
```

As it stands, mobile gets the `float: left` from your original class because the media queries are all `max-width`. To set `float: none` at "mobile" sizes you need to reverse everything, (eg)

```
.leftfloat {
  float: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 420px) {
    .leftfloat {
      float: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call, I didn't notice they had `max-width` instead of `min-width`. That was the error

Comment: Yep, I'm a big advocate of mobile-first CSS too, media querying upwards is a lot easier than the other way round!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property of the child in mobile to be **inherit**.
like this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
       .leftfloat {
         float: inherit;
       }
```